# PHP Compare variables within getimagesize() function

Tags: php, if-statement, getimagesize

I need to apply a condition in the case that an image's width is bigger than, equal to, or smaller than height, but I'm in trouble when I try to compare the variables.

I get width and height values of an image like this:

```
 list($width, $height, $type, $attr) = getimagesize("http://path/image/1photo.jpg");
```

This works fine and I can echo width and height and so on.

Now: if I try to **compare $width with $height** it doesn't work:

```
if($width>$height){
echo 'this';
}
elseif($width<$height){
echo 'that';
}
elseif($width=$height){
echo 'other';
}
```

The above code doesn't work. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Typo:

```
elseif($width=$height){
             ^--- should be ==
```

You're doing an assignment, not a comparison. And since you've eliminated all other possibilities with the `<` and `>` tests, you don't need to test for equality at all, just have:

```
if ($width > $height) {
   ...
} else if ($width < $height) {
   ...
} else {
   ...
}
```

Comment: exactly like that? with 2 else?

Comment: oops. sorry. forgot the `if` on the `<` test. edited the answer.

Comment: maybe there is something else because in my case width is bigger than height and returns me the else statement.

Comment: php wouldn't ever treat `if (3 > 4) { echo "3 is bigger than 4"} ` as true, so if you're getting unexpected outputs, start checking exactly what the inputs are.

Comment: I posted the whole code I have in my file. By the way thank you for your help